# javascript array tree search keep the node and parents

Tags: javascript, search, tree, treeview

Trying to implement a tree search function which takes an array(tree structure) and a string keyword, would return an tree array but only keep the matched nodes and its parents.

```
function search(nodes, keyword){

}



const nodes = [
  {
    value: "1-1",
    children: [
      { value: "1-1-1"},
      { value: "1-1-2", children:[
        {
          value: "1-1-2-1",
          children: [
            { value: "1-1-2-1-1" },
            { value: "1-1-2-1-2" }
          ]
        },
        {
          value: "1-1-2-2"
        }
      ] }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "1-2",
    children: [
      { value: "1-2-1"},
      { value: "1-2-2", children:[
        {
          value: "1-2-2-1",
          children: [
            { value: "1-2-2-1-1" },
            { value: "1-2-2-1-2" }
          ]
        },
        {
          value: "1-2-2-2"
        }
      ] }
    ]
  },
];
```

expected output would be an tree with nodes' values contain "1-1-2-1" and its parents as below

```
const searchedNodes = search(nodes, "1-1-2-1"); 



[
    {
    value: "1-1",
    children: [
      { value: "1-1-2", children:[
        {
          value: "1-1-2-1",
          children: [
            { value: "1-1-2-1-1" }
          ]
        }
      ] }
    ]
  }
]
*/
```

2018-06-26 Updated

I made a working one(DFS) but probably not pretty efficient.

```
const search = (nodes, keyword) => {
    let newNodes = [];
    for (let n of nodes) {
      if (n.children) {
        const nextNodes = this.keywordFilter(n.children, keyword);
        if (nextNodes.length > 0) {
          n.children = nextNodes;
        } else if (n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
          n.children = nextNodes.length > 0 ? nextNodes : [];
        }
        if (
          nextNodes.length > 0 ||
          n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
        ) {

          newNodes.push(n);
        }
      } else {
        if (n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
          newNodes.push(n);
        }
      }
    }
    return newNodes;
  };
```

Comment: what qualifies `'1-1-2-1-1'` and not `'1-1-2-1-2'`? btw, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate the nodes of the same level and check if the value is equal, then take that node and exit the loop. Otherwise check the children and generate a new object for preventing to mutate the original data.

```js
function search(nodes, value) {
    var result;

    nodes.some(o => {
        var children;
        if (o.value === value) {
            return result = o;
        }
        if (o.children && (children = search(o.children, value))) {
            return result = Object.assign({}, o, { children });
        }
    });

    return result && [result];
}


const nodes = [{ value: "1-1", children: [{ value: "1-1-1" }, { value: "1-1-2", children: [{ value: "1-1-2-1", children: [{ value: "1-1-2-1-1" }, { value: "1-1-2-1-2" }] }, { value: "1-1-2-2" }] }] }, { value: "1-2", children: [{ value: "1-2-1" }, { value: "1-2-2", children: [{ value: "1-2-2-1", children: [{ value: "1-2-2-1-1" }, { value: "1-2-2-1-2" }] }, { value: "1-2-2-2" }] }] }];

console.log(search(nodes, "1-1-2-1"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: only the last children is array.  hence this is not right solution

Comment: @SatheeshNatarajan. it returns the wanted node (inclusive all children) and the parents. what goes wrong with it?

Comment: See the input data, which property "children" is an array for all the nested objects. But the output of your code, all the children are object instead of array (except last children).

Comment: @SatheeshNatarajan, sorry, you are right. please see edit.

Comment: Is there a possible to search the match from entire array?

Comment: @SatheeshNatarajan, sorry, i have no idea, what you want. what do you have and waht do you want as result? if it is to complex, please ask a new question with examples and your try.